# Is it possible to make an HTML page and local Javascript library into a Chrome extension with data storage?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript, google-chrome-app

I have been trying to author a Chrome extension recently and have been hitting major problems it seems every step of the way.

Currently I have a local HTML page that is using a local Javascript library.  This works great, except Chrome [limits the amount of data a page can store to 5MB](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage).  I would like to get around this limit, and read that Chrome extensions/applications could use unlimited storage resources via chrome.storage.

While coding, I quickly discovered that this only applies to browser actions, content scripts, and (?) web applications (loading an WWW page as an extension).  I was coding this as a local packaged app, which does NOT have access to either the HTML5 localStorage API NOR the chrome.storage API.  I *really* need the extension to use only local HTML/Javascript resources in order to maintain offline/no-internet functionality.

Can a Chrome web app be loaded from a local resource, i.e. a locally packaged HTML page?  Is there any way around these problems that does not include enabling dangerous security vulnerabilities in Chrome?  I saw that an NPAPI app could solve the problem however that also defeats the purpose of the application I am making.

TIA,
Trann

Comment: [This link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) talks about a flag I might be able to use to get around the 5MB limit.  It appears that [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7540875/613748) suggests I am out of luck, however things may have changed within a years time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is possible with a packaged app, when the correct combination of permissions are put into the manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "fileSystem"
]
```

The fileSystem permission, once added, enabled the FileSystem API to start working as expected (not chrome.storage).